# Manipulate the shape of each character in a string using Java graphics

Tags: java, fonts, vector-graphics

I've figured out how to get the shape of a text string before drawing it on this screen in Java, for example by using the TextLayout class [1]. However I could only find a way to get the Shape of the whole text. I need a Shape for each character in the text. Does anybody know an elegant way of how to obtain the Shape per character?

[1] http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html

Comment: Fonts can also be transformed using font.deriveFont(AffineTransformation at), so I could use AttributedString and attach a different font to every char.. not sure if this is a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a [`GlyphVector`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/GlyphVector.html) object from your `Font`. The returned `GlyphVector` will contain the sequence of glyphs that are used to represent the specified text.

Once you have a `GlyphVector`, you can obtain detailed metrics or a bounding shape for each individual glyph through the `getGlyphMetrics()` and `getGlyphOutline()` methods, respectively.

(Note: The `getGlyphCharIndex()` method can be used to discover the glyph to character mapping.)

Comment: Yes but it gives me all the glyhps of which the characters consist at once, w/o telling me which glyph belongs to which character.. or did I miss something?

Comment: You can use the `getGlyphCharIndex()` method to find out the glyph to character mapping.

Comment: You're welcome. I have updated the answer to include this information.